# Returning raw json (string) in wcf

Tags: wcf, json

I want to build my own JSON, and have the service return a string, here is the code

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string GetCurrentCart()
{
    //Code ommited
    string jsonClient = null;
    var j = new { Content = response.Content, Display=response.Display, SubTotal=response.SubTotal};
    var s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    jsonClient = s.Serialize(j);
    return jsonClient;
}
```

The response I am getting contains the \" used to create "'s in strings in c#.

The following is the response.

```
"{\"Content\":\"\\r\\n\\u003cdiv\\u003e\\r\\n\\u003cinput type=\\\"hidden\\\" name=\\\"__VIEWSTATE\\\" id=\\\"__VIEWSTATE\\\" value=\\\"\/wEPDwUBMA9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYGAgMPFgIeBFRleHQFKFlvdSBoYXZlIG5vIGl0ZW1zIGluIHlvdXIgc2hvcHBpbmcgY2FydC5kAgUPFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZAIHDxQrAAIPFgIfAWhkZGQYAQUMY3RsMDEkbHZDYXJ0D2dkoWijqBUJaUxmDgFrkGdWUM0mLpgQmTOe8R8hc8bZco4=\\\" \/\\u003e\\r\\n\\u003c\/div\\u003e\\r\\n\\r\\n\\u003cdiv class=\\\"block block-shoppingcart\\\"\\u003e\\r\\n    \\u003cdiv class=\\\"title\\\"\\u003e\\r\\n        \\u003cspan\\u003eShopping Cart\\u003c\/span\\u003e\\r\\n    \\u003c\/div\\u003e\\r\\n    \\u003cdiv class=\\\"clear\\\"\\u003e\\r\\n    \\u003c\/div\\u003e\\r\\n    \\u003cdiv class=\\\"listbox\\\"\\u003e\\r\\n        You have no items in your shopping cart.\\r\\n        \\r\\n        \\r\\n    \\u003c\/div\\u003e\\r\\n\\u003c\/div\\u003e\\r\\n\",\"Display\":\"You have no items in your shopping cart.\",\"SubTotal\":null}"
```

The values are being correctly encoded, but the json itself is not properly formatted. These \'s cause it to go out of wack.

How do I return a string without the \'s in front of the "'s?

Comment: when I set ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, the \'s are gone, but of couse the root xml node is there (which I don't want).

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Currently your web method returns a `String` together with `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`. It follows that your code will use the JSON encoding of the string. Corresponding to [json.org](http://www.json.org), this means all double quotes in the string will be escaped using backslashes. So you currently have double JSON encoding.

The easiest way to return any kind of data is to change the output type of the `GetCurrentCart()` web method to `Stream` or `Message` (from `System.ServiceModel.Channels`) instead of `String`.

For code examples, see also...

- Carlos Figueira MSDN blog post, '[WCF "Raw" programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosfigueira/wcf-raw-programming-model-web)',
- MSDN's "[How to: Enable Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx)", and
- MSDN's "[How to: Create a Service That Returns Arbitrary Data Using The WCF REST Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681221(VS.90).aspx)".

Because you don't include in your question which version of .NET you use, I suggest you to use a universal  (and the easiest) way:

```
public Stream GetCurrentCart()
{
    //Code ommitted
    var j = new { Content = response.Content, Display=response.Display,
                  SubTotal=response.SubTotal};
    var s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsonClient = s.Serialize(j);
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType =
        "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonClient));
}
```

Comment: I have wasted hours on this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Oleg thank you so..much i waste the so much of time for this at finally i found this link..Really i thanks to you...

Comment: @Victor: I am glad to hear (to read) that I could help you. You are welcome!

Comment: Hi i have one more issue that when i return the json string at last showing the null can u refer this link once please  http://restaurantmanager.testshell.net/api/Account/GetSetting(0825CA34-CEFF-11E0-84C1-2F0C4824019B,Operation%20Times)

Comment: How can i solve this end the array it  append the  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Stream p1:nil="true" xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />

Comment: @Victor: sorry, but the url which you posted return `<p class="heading1">Service</p><p>Endpoint not found.</p>` error with the HTTP status cod "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found". Do you have a question where you describes your probel? Could you post correct URL?

Comment: Hi Oleg can you test that link in Online Json valid tester in that it showing some errors and when check the view source page it showing the all data.

Comment: when i run this in Fiddler it showing like this   [{"AccountId":1,"AccountNumber":"AC001","AccountType":"Restaurant","BusinessName":"Red Spice Inc","PrimaryContactFirstName":"Varma","PrimaryContactLastName":"Bhupatiraju","PrimaryContactPhone":"(949) 374 2114","PrimaryContactEmail":"redspice@mybusinessapp.com","AccountGuid":"918D3E66-CEFE-11E0-8C2F-0C0B4824019B","EntityState":1,"EntityKey":null}]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Stream p1:nil="true" xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />.

Comment: @Victor: I wrote you before that the link http://restaurantmanager.testshell.net/api/Account/GetSetting(0825CA34-CEFF-11E0-84C1-2F0C4824019B,Operation%20Times which you posted is wrong and return only the error "Endpoint not found." So I can't test anything.

Comment: @Oleg let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3019/discussion-between-victor-and-oleg)

Comment: Thanks ,its really alos help me to get out to this problem that i am facing .Thanks a lot.

Comment: @VikramSE: You are welcome! I'm glad to know that I could help you.

Comment: Do we need to close the memorystream?

Comment: @Pilouk: No, it's not needed.

Comment: Your first link was EXACTLY what I was looking for. return string as json. done. Thanks

Comment: @AdamHey: You are welcome! I'm glad that the old answer still helps.

Answer (score 6):

I tried the method suggested by Oleg but found that when i used this method for a large amount of data null key word was appended at the end of the JSON string.

**Example:** for json with lots of data
{"JsonExample":"xxxxx"}null

found a solution to address this problem at : http://wcf.codeplex.com/workitem/67
Wrote the following function which will accept a object and return a Pure Json output. So before returning my object in the main method i make a call to the below method.

```
  public HttpResponseMessage ReturnPureJson(object responseModel)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        string jsonClient = Json.Encode(responseModel);
        byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonClient);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(resultBytes));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: but you can't use HttpResponseMessage unless you have .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use [**`Jil`**](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil) library to Serialize your JSON object or dynamic(ExpandoObject).

In my case, It will avoid some null value problem, like always get "{}" from `JsonConvert.SerializeXXX` and extend {aa:bb} to {key:aa, value:bb} from `JavaScriptSerializer`

full sample here as below.

**Interface:**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "json/GetCurrentCart")]
Stream GetCurrentCart(MyRequestParam Param);
```

**Implementation:**

```
public Stream GetCurrentCart(MyRequestParam Param)
{
    //code omitted
    dynamic j = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    j.Content = response.Content;
    j.Display = response.Display; 
    j.SubTotal = response.SubTotal;
    string s = Jil.JSON.SerializeDynamic(j);
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That was great (**Oleg** Response) 
   and all make sure that you add the line
 WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType =       "application/json; charset=utf-8";

if you removed it result will be downloaded as file .