# How to change Wcf to use a different serializer?

Tags: wcf

By default WCF use DataContractSerialization so if we can change it then my question is how to change it and when should we need which serialization on wcf ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`XmlSerializerFormatAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute.aspx) attribute on your service contract to force WCF to use the `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 4):

WCF has a nice feature that a method can return `Message` or a `Stream` (see [Returning raw json (string) in wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078397/returning-raw-json-string-in-wcf/3079326#3079326) and [How to set Json.Net as the default serializer for WCF REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118504/how-to-set-json-net-as-the-default-serializer-for-wcf-rest-service/3131413#3131413) as examples). The corresponding code which you need to write can be more easy as if you will use more advance techniques [Extending Encoders and Serializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733092.aspx). So it is very easy to implement [Streaming Message Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) for example or just returning JPG or Excel file as a result of some WCF method.

Answer (score 1):

The default choice of DataContractSerializer is good for most purpose. You can also use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)  specially for REST type services and if the client expects Json content type. The other option is [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx) for interoperability purpose if you need more control over the generated XML. DataContractSerializer  is more efficient than XmlSerializer.

In 3rd party options you can use [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) from Google which is more efficient than DataContract Serializer.