# How to ignore nullable integers when converting from class to Xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF service which has:

```
[DataContract]
public class Attribute
{
      [DataMember]
       public string AttributeUsed1{ get; set; } 

       [DataMember]
       public string AttributeUsed2{ get; set; } 

       [DataMember]
       public string AttributeUsed3{ get; set; } 

       [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
       public int AttributeNotUsed1{ get; set; } 

       [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
       public int? AttributeNotUsed2{ get; set; } 

       [DataMember]
       public string AttributeNotUsed3{ get; set; } 

}
```

Also, I have a windows service which refrences the above webservice.
In this windows service, I have a custom class object and I convert it to XML.

While I build my object for custom class I only set values for AttributeUsed1, AttributeUsed2 and AttributeUsed3. After I serialize my object to XML I get the following:

```
<AttributeUsed1>ABC</AttributeUsed1>
<AttributeUsed2>DEF</AttributeUsed2>
<AttributeUsed3>GHI</AttributeUsed3>
<AttributeNotUsed1>0<AttributeNotUsed1>
<AttributeNotUsed2>xsi: nil="true"</AttributeNotUsed2>
```

My desired result is the following. I do not want integer variables to be displayed at all.
How can I achieve this?. Any help will be much appreciated!:

```
  <AttributeUsed1>ABC</AttributeUsed1>
    <AttributeUsed2>DEF</AttributeUsed2>
    <AttributeUsed3>GHI</AttributeUsed3>
```

Comment: How are you converting it to XML, XmlSerializer, IXmlSerializer, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) based on your use of [`DataContract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`DataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes.

If you really want your integer properties not to be serialized "at all", no matter what their value is, just mark them with the 
[`[IgnoreDataMember]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute:

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
public int? AttributeNotUsed2{ get; set; }
```

Incidentally, when I serialize a your class as-is with default values using `DataContractSerializer`, I don't see `AttributeNotUsed1` or `AttributeNotUsed2`.  I only see elements corresponding to the properties to which you *did not* apply `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]`:

```
<Attribute>
    <AttributeNotUsed3 i:nil="true" />
    <AttributeUsed1 i:nil="true" />
    <AttributeUsed2 i:nil="true" />
    <AttributeUsed3 i:nil="true" />
</Attribute>
```

I.e. your `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]` *is working*.  If you only want to skip emitting default values, add the same attribute to `AttributeNotUsed3` and you are done.

If, on the other hand, [you are actually using `XmlSerializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050938/how-to-change-wcf-to-use-a-different-serializer) with wcf, you need to mark your properties with [`XmlIgnore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
[XmlIgnore]
public int? AttributeNotUsed2{ get; set; }
```

It is safe to apply both attributes; `DataContractSerializer` ignores attributes relevant to `XmlSerializer`, and vice versa.  You can read more about the two serializers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I was not using DataContractSerializer for serializing. After i used it it works fine now. Thank you very much!