# Controlling Namespace Prefixes in WCF XML Output

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, automapper

The current output of my WCF service is as follows (only a portion is shown below):

```
<s:Body>
  <executeSelectSP2Response xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <executeSelectSP2Result xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCF_Services.DataContract" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Rows>
           <a:RowDetail>
              <a:Fields>
                 <a:FieldDetail>
                    <a:name>STATE_CD</a:name>
                    <a:value>1</a:value>
                 </a:FieldDetail>
                 <a:FieldDetail>
                    <a:name>STATE_CD_TXT</a:name>
                    <a:value>Alabama</a:value>
                 </a:FieldDetail>
                 <a:FieldDetail>
                    <a:name>STATE_CD_SHORT_TXT</a:name>
                    <a:value>AL</a:value>
                 </a:FieldDetail>
              </a:Fields>
           </a:RowDetail>
```

In the example, the "RowDetail" element is repeated for each US state.

I have two questions:

1. How can I remove the "a:" prefix in the tags. I am assuming i need to change the xmlns setting, but I am not sure how to do this without throwing an error. I viewed other threads, but could not get it to work.
2. Is it possible to remove the extraneous elements from the output, namely "Rows" and "Fields"? I understand why they are there - it is due to how I set up my classes (posted below), but it is messy to look at IMO.

Classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class Results2Detail
{
    [DataMember]
    public RowDetail[] Rows;
}

[DataContract]
public class RowDetail
{
    [DataMember]
    public FieldDetail[] Fields;
}

[DataContract]
public class FieldDetail
{
    [DataMember]
    public String name;
    [DataMember]
    public String value;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to get rid of the prefixes, or the namespaces? Do you understand that the prefixes are simply abbreviations of the namespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issues here are as follows:

1. You have some outer class corresponding to `executeSelectSP2Response` (not shown in your question) that is being placed in a default namespace `"http://tempuri.org/"` while being serialized.  You probably don't want this since it is the [test default namespace for ASP.Net Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempuri) and you are expected to replace it with a company-specific namespace.

   For instructions in replacing it, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/05/12/how-to-eliminate-tempuri-org-from-your-service-wsdl.aspx) or [here](http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/rebuildall/2010/11/10/WCF_service_namespaces).
2. The [`DataContract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes for the classes shown have no [`NameSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.namespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, so [by default your classes are all to be serialized into the namespace `"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Clr.Namespace"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This differs from the default namespace of their parent element so an override namespace must be specified.  The `a:` prefixes refer to the `xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCF_Services.DataContract"` attribute and specifies that each element so tagged belongs in that namespace.

   If you want to specify that `Results2Detail` et. al. do not belong in a specific namespace (i.e. inherit their namespace from their parent) you can do:

   ```
   [DataContract(Namespace="")]
   public class Results2Detail
   {
       [DataMember]
       public RowDetail[] Rows;
   }

   [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
   public class RowDetail
   {
       [DataMember]
       public FieldDetail[] Fields;
   }

   [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
   public class FieldDetail
   {
       [DataMember]
       public String name;
       [DataMember]
       public String value;
   }
   ```

   If you want a specific namespace, you can do `[DataContract(Namespace = Namespaces.CompanyNameSpace)]` where `Namespaces` is some static class like:

   ```
   public static class Namespaces
   {
       const string CompanyNameSpace = "http://company.namespace.org"; // or whatever.
   }
   ```
3. Your question #2 is unclear.  Are you saying you want your arrays to appear as a single level of elements rather than two nested levels of elements, i.e.:

   ```
   <executeSelectSP2Result>
       <RowDetail>
           <FieldDetail>
           </FieldDetail>
       </RowDetail>
       <RowDetail>
           <FieldDetail>
           </FieldDetail>
       </RowDetail>
   </executeSelectSP2Result>
   ```

   If so, then no, this level of control is not immediately possible with `DataContractSerializer`.  You must either [implement `IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and do it manually,  or [switch to `XmlSerializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050938/how-to-change-wcf-to-use-a-different-serializer) and decorate your arrays with the [`XmlElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answers and associated links. For question #2, that is indeed what I am looking, sorry it was unclear. I will look into using XmlSerializer for this - I have a little experience with that previously.