# Get rid of <a: before xml elements returned by WCF method

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF service with a method that returns the following XML when invoked through Wizdler.

```
  <a:Evaluations>
     <a:Evaluation/>
        <a:Evaluation/>
        <a:Evaluation/>
     <a:Evaluation/>
  </a:Evaluations>
```

I am not creating XML through string builder or with any other thing. This is part of what WCF returns when the method is called.

How to get rid of a: from returned XML.

Comment: You don't - not without changing the *meaning* of the data. Somewhere else within the document, the `a` prefix is associated with an xml namespace. Removing the prefix would put the elements in a different namespace.

Comment: the a: is the namespace prefix, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198159/controlling-namespace-prefixes-in-wcf-xml-output

Comment: @subkonstrukt Thanks. It did the job for me