# web service returns json with some extra tags how can solve this?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-4.0

in my asmx service file i converting dataset to json by newtonsoft .

```
da.Fill(ds);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.None);

            return json;
```

then am getting my response
like this

```
{"d":"{\"Table\":[{\"minlatency\":10.0,\"Time\":\"\\/Date(1328248814197+0530)\\/\"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even if you declare `string` as the returned value of the `Webmethod` the returned data will be serialized one more time with respect of the standard `JavaScriptSerializer`. As the result the data will be **twice** serialized and the value of `d` property of the result will be string where some characters are escaped. If you want continue to use old ASMX web services the simplest solution will be just to parse the string from the `d` property one more time

```
var myData = $.parseJSON(data.d);
```

If you would use WCF services instead of ASMX web services your code will be exactly so simple as before, but you would be able to return *raw data* in very simple way (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733092.aspx)). You can for example use `Message` as the type of returned value of the service method and return *unformatted* string data by the usage of [CreateTextResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.createtextresponse.aspx) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3131413/315935)) or returns `Stream` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3079326/315935)).