# Return named JSON object from c# service in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, service

I have a wcf service in .net, which i want to return a named JSON object. This is how i want to return the JSON object:

```
{"file":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD\/4"}
```

But this is how it is returned from the service in c#

```
"\"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD\/4
```

This is the code i use to return it

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                UriTemplate = "getFile/{fname}")]
    public string GetFile(string name)
    {
        /*
         * Some code (not important)
         */

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(System.Convert.ToBase64String(image));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object with that string as a property. This should work:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
  new { file = System.Convert.ToBase64String(image) }
);
```

Comment: Thanks!, almost. However it returns this "{\"file\":\"\/9}" and i want to return this {"file":"\/9}. Maybe i have to correct this in php?

Comment: I fixed this problem by returning a stream instead. According to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078397/returning-raw-json-string-in-wcf

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an new object.

```
var file = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(System.Convert.ToBase64String(image));
return Json(new {file},JsonRequstBehavior.AllowGet);
```