# What will be equivalent C# class for this JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf

**JSON:**

```
[
    {
        "ProspectNo": "1000000073",
        "MakerId": "C136771",
        "MkrDate": "2015/11/26",
        "TranID": null,
        "ScoreData": {
            "Client Experience": "1",
            "Stability & Ownership": "7",
            "Property ownership": "22",
            "Co-app/Guarantor": "16",
            "proposed cost": "1800000"
        }
    }
]
```

This is my attempted class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Score
{
    [DataMember()]
    public string ProspectNo;

    [DataMember()]
    public string MakerId;

    [DataMember()]
    public string MkrDate;

    //[DataMember()]
    //public string ScoreData;
    [DataMember()]
    //public Dictionary<string, string> ScoreData { get; set; }
    public List<ScoreDataClass> ScoreData;

    [DataMember()]
    public string TranID;
}

[DataContract]
public class ScoreDataClass
{
    [DataMember()]
    public string key { get; set; }
    [DataMember()]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that in my method :

```
public Main CalculateScore(Score scoreobj)
{
    //ScoreData count is always 0. 
}
```

Everything is fine except that I never get values in ScoreData.

I tried various Json to C# class generators available online  such as  http://jsonutils.com/  but it did not give desired results.

The JSON string will be sent from client as httppost. I can not change the way it is being sent.

**NOTE:** 
*I can not hard code it as `(Name="Client Experience")` etc since I do not know how many or what its going be. It is not necessary that its always going to be Client Experience it could be anything.*

Comment: You can use online tool for that purpose: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @CodeCaster yes it is.

Comment: Is this not what you are really after ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806811/dynamic-objects-in-wcf-not-possible

Comment: Here's a tip for future reference: `Copy your json` then in Visual studio goto `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Json as C# class`.

Answer (score 2):

JSON objects can be translated into `Dictionary<string, object>`, but not a list of your custom class with key and value properties.

I have used `Dictionary<string, string>`, because it seems your object has string values only.
You can use the following class definition:

```
public class Score
{
    public string ProspectNo { get; set; }
    public string MakerId { get; set; }
    public string MkrDate { get; set; }
    public string TranID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> ScoreData { get; set; }
}
```

That's how you should serialize it:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Score[]>(jsonString);
```

Note that it is `Score[]`, but not `Score`, because your JSON represents an array of `Score` objects.

After serialization, you will be able to access this dictionary like this:

```
result[0].ScoreData["Stability & Ownership"] // 7
```

**Result of execution:**

[image: My example]

Comment: My first try was ` public Dictionary<string, string> ScoreData { get; set; }` but it too seemed to have zero items in wcf method.

Comment: @Arbaaz I just have checked this - it works. See my update. Probably, you are deserializing it wrong.

Comment: How can I add `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Score[]>(jsonString);` in `CalculateScore` method?  I mean what am I gonna pass for `jsonString` ?

Comment: @Arbaaz you can't, WCF REST does the deserialization for you.

Comment: In that case I am back at square one

Comment: @Arbaaz no you're not, see [my reply to you under my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287861/what-will-be-equivalent-c-sharp-class-for-this-json/34287915#comment56318260_34288173). You can create a dictionary.

Comment: @CodeCaster I already tried dictionary. It always shows zero item count.

Answer (score 1):

Given this is a WCF REST service, you can use the `[DataMember]` attribute to rename the properties of the generated classes.

```
public class ScoreData
{
    [DataMember(Name="Client Experience")]
    public string ClientExperience { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="Stability & Ownership")]
    public string StabilityOwnership { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="Property ownership")]
    public string PropertyOwnership { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="Co-app/Guarantor")]
    public string CoAppGuarantor { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="proposed cost")]
    public string ProposedCost { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public string ProspectNo { get; set; }
    public string MakerId { get; set; }
    public string MkrDate { get; set; }
    public object TranID { get; set; }
    public ScoreData ScoreData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I can not hard code it as `(Name="Client Experience")` etc since I do not know how many or what its going be. It is not necessary that its always going to be `Client Experience` it could be anything.

Comment: The see [Generic WCF JSON Deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297903/generic-wcf-json-deserialization) to create a dictionary of your `ScoreData`.