# Data from GetResponseStream

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, json.net, system.net.httpwebrequest

How can I get the sub_category_en on this data I receive from HttpWebRequest? 
I just want the two to three fields on the data received.

`02-14 16:33:56.793 I/mono-stdout( 8974):   {
02-14 16:33:56.795 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "active": 1,
02-14 16:33:56.797 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "child_level": 1,
02-14 16:33:56.798 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "create_date": "2015-08-27T17:24:58.19+03:00",
02-14 16:33:56.798 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "description_ar": "",
02-14 16:33:56.800 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "description_en": "",
02-14 16:33:56.802 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "has_child": 1,
02-14 16:33:56.805 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "id": 1881,
02-14 16:33:56.805 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "id_category": 3,
02-14 16:33:56.808 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "id_parent": 0,
02-14 16:33:56.811 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "id_parents": "0",
02-14 16:33:56.811 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "id_user": 1,
02-14 16:33:56.811 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "last_update": "2015-08-27T17:24:58.19+03:00",
02-14 16:33:56.814 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "last_updated_by": 1,
02-14 16:33:56.815 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "meta_keyword_ar": "",
02-14 16:33:56.815 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "meta_keyword_en": "",
02-14 16:33:56.815 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "order_by": 94,
02-14 16:33:56.815 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_ar": "Trailers",
02-14 16:33:56.815 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_en": "Trailers",
02-14 16:33:56.816 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_name_parents_ar": null,
02-14 16:33:56.816 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_name_parents_en": null,
02-14 16:33:56.816 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_url": "trailers",
02-14 16:33:56.816 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_url_parents": null
02-14 16:33:56.816 I/mono-stdout( 8974):   },
02-14 16:33:56.817 I/mono-stdout( 8974):   {
02-14 16:33:56.817 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "active": 1,
02-14 16:33:56.817 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "child_level": 1,
02-14 16:33:56.817 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "create_date": "2015-08-27T17:25:14.31+03:00",
02-14 16:33:56.817 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "description_ar": "",
02-14 16:33:56.818 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "description_en": "",
02-14 16:33:56.818 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "has_child": 1,
02-14 16:33:56.818 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "id": 1882,
02-14 16:33:56.818 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "id_category": 3,
02-14 16:33:56.818 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "id_parent": 0,
02-14 16:33:56.818 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "id_parents": "0",
02-14 16:33:56.819 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "id_user": 1,
02-14 16:33:56.819 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "last_update": "2015-08-27T17:25:14.31+03:00",
02-14 16:33:56.819 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "last_updated_by": 1,
02-14 16:33:56.819 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "meta_keyword_ar": "",
02-14 16:33:56.819 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "meta_keyword_en": "",
02-14 16:33:56.820 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "order_by": 95,
02-14 16:33:56.820 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_ar": "Aeroplanes",
02-14 16:33:56.820 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_en": "Aeroplanes",
02-14 16:33:56.820 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_name_parents_ar": null,
02-14 16:33:56.820 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_name_parents_en": null,
02-14 16:33:56.821 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_url": "aeroplanes",
02-14 16:33:56.821 I/mono-stdout( 8974):     "sub_category_url_parents": null
02-14 16:33:56.821 I/mono-stdout( 8974):   }
02-14 16:33:56.821 I/mono-stdout( 8974): ]`

I used xamarin in visual studio 2013.. Thanks for helping. If using this Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer is the ey on my problem. Can I have a small sample code? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JsonConvert.Deserialize](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) to convert json to a custom object.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string sub_category_name { get; set; }
    public int child_level { get; set; }
    public int has_child { get; set; }
    public string sub_parent_url { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(dest);
      WebResponse objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
      {
        string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonString);

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having error on JArray data = JArray.Parse(jsonString);   jsonString= "\"[{\\\"id\\\":44,\\\"sub_category_name\\\":\\\"Cars For Sale\\\",\\\"child_level\\\":1,\\\"has_child\\\":1,\\\"sub_parent_url\\\":null,\\\"sub_cat_url\\\":\\\"cars-for-sale\\\"},{\\\"id\\\":892,\\\"sub_category_name\\\":\\\"Cars for Rent\\\",\\\"child_lev.........    I get that jsonString from  var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

Comment: You are getting an error when you are reading your json. I have updated the answer, assuming you are reading from a file

Comment: If you are hard-coding the values into `jsonString`, you do not need to use `reader.ReadToEnd()`

Comment: no I'm not hardcoding the valuw of jsonstring. I just give the data of jasonstring that I get from the httwebresponse

Comment: Could you update the question with the code you are using to read the json?

Comment: I want o get the data of sub_category_en and sub_category_url. I am using HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse; StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

Comment: See updated answer. Are you sure you are receiving a valide json? Use http://pro.jsonlint.com/ to validate your json.

Comment: JArray data = JArray.Parse(jsonString); where is the jsonString in yur sample code?

Comment: I tried the json that I am getting from your link. the json data is valid

Comment: I get this error "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: String. Path '', line 1, position 1574." pointing at  JArray data = JArray.Parse(json);

Comment: Could you send med the url?

Comment: http://192.168.1.136:2504/Service1.svc/getsub_category/0/1/Motors that's the sample

Comment: I am unable to connect to the server. But using `HttpWebRequest` should be able to consume your service. Have a look at this article: http://codewala.net/2014/01/06/how-to-consume-wcf-rest-services-using-c/

Comment: this is the json data I get "[{\"id\":44,\"sub_category_name\":\"Cars For Sale\",\"child_level\":1,\"has_child\":1,\"sub_parent_url\":null,\"sub_cat_url\":\"cars-for-sale\"},{\"id\":896,\"sub_category_name\":\"Motorcycles\",\"child_level\":1,\"has_child\":1,\"sub_parent_url\":null,\"sub_cat_url\":\"motorcycles\"},{\"id\":897,\"sub_category_name\":\"Cars Plates For Sale\",\"child_level\":1,\"has_child\":0,\"sub_parent_url\":null,\"sub_cat_url\":\"cars-plates-for-sale\"}]"

Comment: I am guessing the problem is that you have double set of JSON encoding, hence all the backslashes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078397/returning-raw-json-string-in-wcf. The code works fine when I read it locally without the backslashes, but break with them.

Comment: double set of JSON encoding in Web Service? no, Its only a single json return. And I receive "[{\"id\":44,\"sub_category_name\":\"Cars For Sale\"... data of like that. the problem now is on the JArray data = JArray.Parse(json); saying Current JsonReader item is not an array.

Comment: Thank you very much sjokkogutten

Comment: No worries mate. Let's try a different approach, see the updated answer