# svc webservice response contains extra double qotation

Tags: c#, json, web-services, svc

I have a json stored in database in a ntext field, I want to return that in a svc (c#) webservice , webservice is get and response type is string such as below :

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "gcwbcc/{cityCode}/{key}")]
```

but in result i get extra double qutation  also all double qutions in json converts to \" then I have two problems one is extra double qutation , and second is convertint " to \" in result.

Comment: That is a escaped JSON string. `{ "prop" : "value" }` will become `"{\"prop\":\"value\"}"` seems that the code is treating the json stored as just a simple string, you may have to parse it and return an object and then return it, or maybe you can send it as a raw response and then it wont get escaped.

Comment: hi, thanks for adding comment, is there any build in object which can I cast string to it . I test webservice with a single string "a" and " shows in response, I want the response just be a not "a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by changing return type of web method to stream 
and with writing this simple line of code:

byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            return new MemoryStream(resultBytes);

refrence:
[Returning raw json (string) in wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078397/returning-raw-json-string-in-wcf/3079326#3079326)
but here is original guide
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web/