# Remove internal "__type" tags in ASP.NET Restful WCF

Tags: asp.net, json, rest, serialization

I'm developing a RESTful WCF, and am currently having trouble getting nice, clean JSON-serialized return values.

[A little while back, I got rid of "Key" and "Value" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590088/make-asp-net-wcf-convert-dictionary-to-json-omitting-key-value-tags) around each of my keys and values (caused by serializing a `Dictionary<string, object>` object) by using a wrapper.

But when I did that, "__type" tags started showing up.  I managed to get rid of the "d" tag, along with the first "__type" tag by replacing WebScriptServiceHostFactory with WebServiceHostFactory in the ServiceHost tag of my svc file.

So my result looks like this:

```
{"Status":"Success","Data":{"__type":"SerializableDictionaryOfstringanyType:#MyNamespace.MyFolder","Key1":"Value1","Key2":"Value2","Key3":"Value3"}}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
{"Status":"Success","Data":{"Key1":"Value1","Key2":"Value2","Key3":"Value3"}}
```

My test webservice code looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public SerializableDictionary<string, object> Test1(String Token, String Id)
{
    DataTable testTable = new DataTable();
    testTable.Columns.Add("Key1", typeof(System.String));
    testTable.Columns.Add("Key2", typeof(System.String));
    testTable.Columns.Add("Key3", typeof(System.String));

    DataRow testRow = testTable.NewRow();
    testRow["Key1"] = "Value1";
    testRow["Key2"] = "Value2";
    testRow["Key3"] = "Value3";

    testTable.Rows.Add(testRow);

    return SuccessfulResult(testTable);
}
```

**EDIT:** And the SuccessfulResult function looks like this (sorry for forgetting it):

```
private SerializableDictionary<string, object> SuccessfulResult(DataTable dt = null)
{
    SerializableDictionary<string, object> result = new SerializableDictionary<string, object>();
    result.Add("Status", "Success");

    if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count != 1)
        return result;

    SerializableDictionary<string, object> dct = new SerializableDictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn currCol in dt.Rows[0].Table.Columns)
        dct.Add(currCol.ColumnName, dt.Rows[0][currCol.ColumnName].ToString());

    result.Add("Data", dct);

    return result;
}
```

If anybody has any ideas on how I might get rid of that last little "__type" tag, I would love to hear them!  Thanks very much, and let me know if there's anything else I can post that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, fixed it up - but ended up doing things a little differently.  WCF seems to insist on putting in those internal "__type" tags when it serializes Dictionaries, but for some reason, it doesn't do the same thing with Streams.

**Here's the new webservice method code** (just the return type has changed):

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Stream Test1(String Token, String StreamId)
{
    DataTable testTable = new DataTable();
    testTable.Columns.Add("Key1", typeof(System.String));
    testTable.Columns.Add("Key2", typeof(System.String));
    testTable.Columns.Add("Key3", typeof(System.String));

    DataRow testRow = testTable.NewRow();
    testRow["Key1"] = "Value1";
    testRow["Key2"] = "Value2";
    testRow["Key3"] = "Value3";

    testTable.Rows.Add(testRow);

    return SuccessfulResult(testTable);
}
```

**And here's the new SuccessfulResult function** (which is what made the difference):

```
private Stream SuccessfulResult(DataTable dt = null)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> returnDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    returnDict.Add("Status", "Success");

    Dictionary<string,object> dct = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    foreach (DataColumn currCol in dt.Rows[0].Table.Columns)
        dct.Add(currCol.ColumnName, dt.Rows[0][currCol.ColumnName].ToString());

    returnDict.Add("Data", dct);

    string sResponse = json.Serialize(returnDict);
    byte[] byResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sResponse);

    return new MemoryStream(byResponse);
}
```

Now the output looks exactly how I want it to look:

```
{"Status":"Success","Data":{"Key1":"Value1","Key2":"Value2","Key3":"Value3"}}
```

Anyway, I hope this example helps somebody else  :)

Comment: It's a good hack, but there's got to be a more "built-in" way of doing this. :-/

Comment: It's absolutely working, a little configuration make it simple & on the fly function. the point is -> byte[] byResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string); return new MemoryStream(byResponse);

Answer (score 0):

In some case, the browser will treat response stream as binary, so, it will show download file popup.
Then you should using:

```
string result = "Hello world";
byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
return new MemoryStream(resultBytes);
```

Answer (score -1):

I know that this was a long time ago, but I found a really simple way to make that possible.

In the Web.Config file you should change a line.

Use `<webHttp/>` instead of `<enableWebScript/>`

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
```

Comment: It was in the opposite way, you should use <webHttp />.