# change json object wrapper name returned from wcf service method

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf, wcf-binding

I have created a WCF 3.5 application with a method named `TestMe` as defined below:

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Login", Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        MyDictionary<string, string> TestMe(string param1, string param2);
```

`MyDictionary` is created using this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590189/546033

Everything here works fine. But the problem is when returning the data from the implemented method below:

```
MyDictionary<string, string> success = new MyDictionary<string, string>();
success["desc"] = "Test";
return success;
```

it returns following json:

```
{"TestMeResult":{"desc":"Test"}}
```

while what i need is:

```
{"success":{"desc":"Test"}}
```

where `success` is the object name. What can be the workaround for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [MessageParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messageparameterattribute.aspx) attribute.

> Controls the name of the request and response parameter names.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Login", Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] 
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "success")]
    MyDictionary<string, string> TestMe(string param1, string param2);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. but suppose if i have an error on server and want to return message parameter as `success` or `error` based on condition. how it could be done?

Answer (score 4):

Just remove BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
it defaults to WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, but have to explicitly declare it yourself.

**EDIT:**

Since you are dealing with JSON  is not going to help becuase it works for XML style. So steps are:

1. declare it bare so you can send json.
2. write your own wrapper using json deserializer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)

You may also check this link to find out whats going on internally:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx

Comment: i dont want to remove the wrapper, but i want to change it. Hope u read the question carefully

Comment: This solved my problem as it always wrapping the json in a parent object that seemed to e called /Result. Putting this on my object made it work
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            UriTemplate = "/{key}/{filter}",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]