# Serialize a Dictionary<string,Type> and remove key/value from JSON string

Tags: c#, json, datacontractserializer

I have following code snippet in which I am serializing an object into JSON. The code is working fine, but I want to remove `Key` and `Value` keywords from the JSON string.

**Current output:**

```
{
   "Description":"test",
   "RoomTypes":[
      {
         "Key":"A",
         "Value":{
            "Name":"Delux"
         }
      },
      {
         "Key":"B",
         "Value":{
            "Name":"Non delux"
         }
      }
   ],
   "Url":"http:\/\/test.com"
}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{
   "Description":"test",
   "RoomTypes":[
      {
         "A":{
            "Name":"Delux"
         }
      },
      {
         "B":{
            "Name":"Non delux"
         }
      }
   ],
   "Url":"http:\/\/test.com"
}
```

**My test code:**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Room
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Dictionary<string, RoomTypes> RoomTypes { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class RoomTypes
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Room room = new Room { Url = "http://test.com", Description="test" };
            RoomTypes roomType1 = new RoomTypes() { Name = "Delux" };
            RoomTypes roomType2 = new RoomTypes() { Name = "Non delux" };
            room.RoomTypes = new Dictionary<string, RoomTypes>();
            room.RoomTypes["A"] = roomType1;
            room.RoomTypes["B"] = roomType2;

            DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractSer = 
                   new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Room));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            dataContractSer.WriteObject(ms, room);
            var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Brian: argh - I checked only after my post... you resurrected a 3 year old question... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not fun, but try this:

```
[Test]
public void Json()
{
         var input = @"{
   ""Description"":""test"",
   ""RoomTypes"":[
      {
         ""Key"":""A"",
         ""Value"":{
            ""Name"":""Delux""
         }
      },
      {
         ""Key"":""B"",
         ""Value"":{
            ""Name"":""Non delux""
         }
      }
   ],
   ""Url"":""http:\/\/test.com""
}";

    var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Temp>(input);
    var transform = new Transform
        {
            Description = temp.Description,
            Url = temp.Url,
            RoomTypes = new List<IDictionary<string, Temp.NameObj>>()
        };

    foreach (var group in temp.RoomTypes)
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, Temp.NameObj> {{@group.Key, @group.Value}};
        transform.RoomTypes.Add(dic);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transform));
}

public class Transform
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<IDictionary<string, Temp.NameObj>> RoomTypes { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}


public class Temp
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<GroupObj> RoomTypes { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public class GroupObj
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public NameObj Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class NameObj
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The idea is to use Json.Net's dictionary serialization to achieve the structure you want.

Comment: Is it possible without using Json.Net?

Comment: I have just tested it using DataContractJsonSerializer, and it will not serialize to the way you wanted out of the box. It will return something like this: `"RoomTypes":[[{"Key":"A","Value":{"Name":"Delux"}}]`. If you try using ExpandoObject, it will fail at the serialization level. I am not exactly sure how this can be done using DataContractJsonSerializer :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the .NET Framework v4.5 or later you can set the `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` setting to `true` to get closer to the format you want:

```
var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;

var dataContractSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Room), settings);
```

Using the test code from the question with the above modification produces the following output, which *may* be what you are looking for (although it differs from the desired output as stated in the question):

```
{
  "Description": "test",
  "RoomTypes": {
    "A": {
      "Name": "Delux"
    },
    "B": {
      "Name": "Non delux"
    }
  },
  "Url": "http://test.com"
}
```

Comment: Took me a while to get to this answer. I don't want to add another dependency to my project _just_ to be able to read key-value pairs from a JSON-file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using dictionary for storing the value. You have to write a custom implementation and overide serialization/deserialization methods

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590088/make-asp-net-wcf-convert-dictionary-to-json-omitting-key-value-tags) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you don't want to use Json.NET, but seriously, this is the library built-to-purpose for handling JSON serialization. Your requirement is fully met by Json.NET and all you need to do is write it as a single line of code...

**(From the documentation:)**

```
Dictionary<string, int> points = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "James", 9001 },
    { "Jo", 3474 },
    { "Jess", 11926 }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(points, Formatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(json);
// {
//   "James": 9001,
//   "Jo": 3474,
//   "Jess": 11926
// }
```

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializedictionary.htm

Answer (score -2):

simply you can modify your string with string replace function try This

```
>   public string updatejson (string jsonorg)
>     {
>         string updatedjson = "";
>         updatedjson = jsonorg.Replace("\"Key\":", "");
>         updatedjson = updatedjson.Replace("\"Value\":", "");
>         updatedjson = updatedjson.Replace("\",", "\":");
>         updatedjson = updatedjson.Replace("},{", ",");
>         updatedjson = updatedjson.TrimStart('[');
>         updatedjson = updatedjson.TrimEnd(']');
> 
>         return updatedjson;
>     }
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is a terribly fragile solution and will produce invalid JSON depending on the formatting and/or contents of the source JSON.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/JiwLN5 for an example.

Comment: yeah I know this thing. we have to modify our code as per requirement. I am not saying this is the solution I have only shared a quick fix for this type of problem.