# WCF REST service dictionary serialization

Tags: wcf, dictionary, datacontractjsonserializer, json-serialization

I'm having trouble with serializing dictionary in my WCF service.

```
[DataContract]
    public class UserInfo
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public IDictionary<string, List<string>> Permissions { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    }
```

This is example of current response

```
{
    "ID": "1",
    "Name": "admin",
    "Permissions": [
        {
            "Key": "Users",
            "Value": [
                "Read",
                "Edit"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Key": "Management",
            "Value": [
                "Read"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and  this is desired response

```
{
    "ID": "1",
    "Name": "admin",
    "Permissions": {
        "Users": ["Read", "Edit"],
        "Management": ["Read"]
    }
}
```

Is there way to implement this globally or on specific property?

Comment: Here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590189/5519709

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that solution, though I'll leave a question a bit longer to see if someone posts any serialization solution.

Comment: So did it worked?

Comment: When using AjaxDictionary<string, string[]> I'm getting - Type 'System.String[]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfstring:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by using custom made dictionary as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590088/make-asp-net-wcf-convert-dictionary-to-json-omitting-key-value-tags/7590189#7590189).

Since I've created this type for serialization

```
AjaxDictionary<string, string[]>
```

I had to add

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(string[]))]
```

on my `class` that is `ServiceContract` for returning responses.