# Json serialization of a nested Dictionary returns { "key": "key1", "value": "value1" }

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I'm currently working on a webservice, and I have this behavior that I haven't encountered until today. Here's the class I'm returning:

```
public class Block
{
    public int order { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> attributes { get; set; }
}
```

`attributes` can contain any kind of value: simple type, object, array, etc.

And when I return a `Block` object through my webservice, here's what I get:

```
{
    "order": 1,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "Key": "key1",
            "Value": "value1"
        },
        {
            "Key": "key2",
            "Value": "value2"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Title"
}
```

Does anyone know why I'm not simply getting a `"key1": "value1"` output?

Comment: Perhaps you can show us the code you're using to serialise the object!

Answer (score 1):

First of all your JSON is not valid, please be aware there are no `,` after `"order": 1` this line.

After this correction you can change your class structure like this

```
    public class Attribute
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Block
    {
        public int order { get; set; }
        public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
```

this way you will be able to deserialize your JSON, I used simply this website https://json2csharp.com/ for converting your JSON into C# class

As for usage you can do .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Key=="key1") to get whichever data you want, or if you will process all the list one by one you can simply do attributes.Count

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but looks like you're missing the point here.

First, I'm generating a json from a C# class, so using json2csharp will do the opposite of what I need.

Then, I do not want to have a ```"key": "key1", "value": "value1"``` in my json output, which is exactly what this Attribute class will do.

Answer (score 1):

When I do

```
    var x = new Class
    {
        order = 1,
        title = "Title",
        attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "key1", "value1" },
            { "key2", "value2" }
        }
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
```

I get

```
{"order":1,"title":"Title","attributes":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}
```

Do you have code that serializes your data or does ASP.NET do it for you?

Comment: ASP.NET does it for me. And when I serialize it with Newtonsoft.json I have the same output than you.

Comment: @Skefrep I just tried it with a .NET core 3.1 project and ASP.NET serializes it 'correctly' as well. What framework are you using?

Comment: I tried making a 4.8 project and added `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"))` to the WebApiConfig and it also serializes like you'd expect. Can you show your controller and WebApiConfig?

Comment: OK, I finally found another question which is the same problem that I have:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590088/make-asp-net-wcf-convert-dictionary-to-json-omitting-key-value-tags

I didn't know that WCF had a different behavior regarding serialization.