# How to give a alias to class name using Attributes of System.ComponentModel namespace

Tags: c#, .net

When I am rendering data of my class using JSON to web page
then my class name is being rendered as full name including complete namespace
What is the way using attribute in C# that i can give some alias to class name.

I dont want to expose complete name of class like
{"mycompany.productname.classname":"somevalue"}

I want to render it like
{"classname":"somevalue"}

Below is the code of Receivings.aspx.cs
//Contains Interaction logic for Receivings.aspx

```
   public partial class Receivings : Page
    {                
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static object GetReceivingDetails(int pId)
    {
        try
        {
            RecDetail recDetail = new AccountsBL().GetReceivingDetails(pId);

            //Return result to jTable
            return new { Result = "OK", Records = recDetail };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message };
        }
    }
}
```

JSON rendered is shown below

[image]

Here is JSOn as shown in above screenshot

```
{"d":{"Result":"OK","Records":{"__type":"ERP.Models.Accounts.RecDetail","Id":0,"Mode":0,"Amount":0,"CatId":0,"CatTypeId":0,"RecId":0,"PayerId":0,"Cash":{"Id":1,"Thousand":30,"FiveHundred":0,"Hundred":0,"Fifty":0,"Twenty":0,"Ten":0,"Five":0,"Two":0,"One":0,"RecId":0,"PayerId":0,"CashRec":30000,"Notes":"xccxvcxcvzc"},"Cheque":{"Id":5,"Bank":"HDFC","Branch":"6868","No":"452326424","Date":"5/5/2013 12:00:00 AM","Amount":10000,"RecId":0,"PayerId":0,"Notes":"asdfasdfasdf"},"DD":{"Id":1,"Bank":"SBI","Branch":"354356","No":"141234123","Date":"5/5/2013 12:00:00 AM","Amount":10000,"RecId":0,"PayerId":0,"Notes":"sdfgsfdgsdfg"}}}}
```

Below is RecDetail class

```
namespace ERP.Models.Accounts
{
    [ERPAttributes("RecDetail")]
    public class RecDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public byte Mode { get; set; }

        public int Amount { get; set; }

        public byte CatId { get; set; }

        public byte CatTypeId { get; set; }

        public int RecId { get; set; }

        public int PayerId { get; set; }

        public Cash Cash { get; set; }

        public Cheque Cheque { get; set; }

        public DD DD { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Serializer you are using?

Comment: I am using ASP.net inbuilt JSOn serializer i haven' mentioned any specific serializer anywhere in project even not in web.config

Comment: Try overriding `ToString()` method on that class.

Comment: i've found a way to remove it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437472/how-to-remove-d-and-type-from-json-response-for-asp-web-service?lq=1

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Overriding not working :(

Comment: From looking at the source of the used JavascriptSerializer its more or less hardcoded. Any solution should be more or less a hack. Can you instead just return a string instead of the object and do the Json conversion yourself? JSON.Net for example can be parametrized to leave typeinfomation away.