# jqGrid does not show rows

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, wcf-rest

I am trying to display the rows in jqGrid (4.3.2)and havn't got success yet. My webservice response is:

```
{"d":
{"__type":"JSONResponse:pe",
 "ActionType":null,
 "JSONData":"
            {\"total\":1,
             \"page\":1,
             \"records\":5,
             \"rows\":[
                       {\"invid\":1,\"cell\":[{\"invid\":1,\"amount\":500,\"tax\":65,\"total\":565,\"note\":\"myNote 0\"}]},
                       {\"invid\":2,\"cell\":[{\"invid\":2,\"amount\":510,\"tax\":75,\"total\":585,\"note\":\"myNote 1\"}]},
                       {\"invid\":3,\"cell\":[{\"invid\":3,\"amount\":520,\"tax\":85,\"total\":605,\"note\":\"myNote 2\"}]},
                       {\"invid\":4,\"cell\":[{\"invid\":4,\"amount\":530,\"tax\":95,\"total\":625,\"note\":\"myNote 3\"}]},
                       {\"invid\":5,\"cell\":[{\"invid\":5,\"amount\":540,\"tax\":105,\"total\":645,\"note\":\"myNote 4\"}]}
                      ]
            }",
 "Status":false
}
```

} <- (assume this curly braces in above code)

My Grid Config look like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        gridConfig();

    });

    function gridConfig() {
        var request = JSON.stringify(requestData());
        var jsonResponse;

        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/ScriptServices/JsonService.svc/Process',
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            datatype: 'json',
            postData: { request: function () { return request; } },
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Inv No', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'invid', index: 'invid', width: 55 },
                    { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: 'right' },
                    { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: 'right' },
                    { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: 'right' },
                    { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
                  ],
            pager: $('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sortname: 'invid',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            jsonReader: {
                root: "d.JSONData.rows",
                page: "d.JSONData.page",
                total: "d.JSONData.total",
                records: "d.JSONData.records",
                cell: "cell",
                id:0
            },
            caption: 'My first grid'
        });

    };

    function requestData() {
        var request;
        request = {
            ActionType: 'GET_GRID_DATA',
            RequestJSONData: '{ }'
        };
        return request;
    }

</script>
```

I am not able to find the issue. Is any other formatting needed. Help please..

**Update1:**

Now my data is coming in proper json format after Oleg suggestion, but because of __type extra field in my json data, its not rendering correctly.

Modified json data looks like:-

```
{
"d":
    {"__type":"JSONResponse:pe",
     "ActionType":"GRID_RESP",
     "JSONData":
                {"__type":"JQGridJSONReader:pe",
                "total":1,
                "page":1,
                "records":5,
                "rows":[
                        {"__type":"InvoiceGrid:pe",
                        "invid":1,
                        "cell":[{"__type":"JqGridCell:pe","invid":1,"amount":500,"tax":65,"total":565,"note":"myNote 0"}]},
                        .... and More Rows
                        ]
                },
     "Status":true
}
```

} <- (assume this curly braces in above code)

I have checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/627356/907176) and implemented the default constructor suggestion, `protected internal` is not possible in my case.

My Service config look like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="JsonService" behaviorConfiguration="JsonServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="JsonServiceEndPointBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JsonService" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="JsonServiceEndPointBehavior">
                <enableWebScript/>
              <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="JsonServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

If I apply `<webHttp/>` to `endpointBehaviors` I get "Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'" error.

My WebService look like this:-

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.abhishek.com/portal/json")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class JsonService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    [GenerateScriptType(typeof(JsonService), ScriptTypeId = "JsonService1")]
    public PresentationEntities.JSONResponse Process(PresentationEntities.JSONRequest request)
    {
        JSONResponse response;

        try
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("request", string.Format(ExceptionHelper.ARG_NULL_EXP_MSG, "JSONManager"));
            }
            else
            {
                JQGridTransalator gridtransalator = new JQGridTransalator();
                response = gridtransalator.JQGridToJSONResponse(); // fill response.JSONData with JQGridJSONReader
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return response;
    }}
```

JQGridJSONReader look like this:-

```
[DataContract(Name = "JQGridJSONReader", Namespace = "pe")]
public class JQGridJSONReader
{
    public JQGridJSONReader()
    {

    }

    [DataMember(Name = "total", Order = 1)]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "page", Order = 2)]
    public int Page { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "records", Order = 3)]
    public int Records { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "rows", Order = 4)]
    public List<InvoiceGrid> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestion to remove __type from the json data.

**Update2:**

Updating the code so that I can answer my question more clearly

```
[DataContract(Name = "InvoiceGrid", Namespace = "pe")]
public class InvoiceGrid
{
    [DataMember(Name = "cell", Order = 2)]
    public List<JqGridCell> Cell { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "JqGridCell", Namespace = "pe")]
public class JqGridCell
{
    [DataMember(Name = "invid", Order = 1)]
    public int Invid { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "invdate", Order = 2)]
    public DateTime InvDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "amount", Order = 3)]
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "tax", Order = 4)]
    public double Tax { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "total", Order = 5)]
    public double Total { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "note", Order = 6)]
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you serialize object with data `d.JSONData` from object to JSON **twice**. Probably you used some JSON serialization manually instead of usage object and allow .NET to serialize the data itself.

How you can see the data like `d.JSONData.rows` can't be accessed because `d.JSONData` is *string* instead of object having `rows` property.

Comment: I have corrected my json data, now its coming good. but __type is the extra field I am getting along with json data which affect my jsonReader format. please see the **Update1**

Comment: I got the error. Error is in `"cell":[{"__type":"JqGridCell:pe","invid":1,"amount":500,"tax":65,"total":565,"note":"myNote 0"}]},`. soon I will be posting the answer. Thanks @Oleg to giving me hint about how to convert .net object to json object.

Comment: Yes I was using JSON serialization manually. Corrected that. May be in future I will never doing that because ASP.NET already to it for me when sending the response. :)

Answer (score 0):

First mistake corrected:-
As suggested by @Oleg I converted JSONData (was in string format) to json object. This was due to JSON serialization used before sending the data.

Second mistake corrected:-

My cell type was like this: `List<GridData>` and GridData had the cell content(which is complex type i.e. `GridData`). So I was getting this

`"cell":[{"__type":"JqGridCell:pe","invid":1,"amount":500,"tax":65,"total":565,"n‌​ote":"myNote 0"}]},` In this cell is having a Complex type as first row. imagine like `"cell":[{ComplexType}]` So I was getting "[Object object]" in my first cell and other cells remain empty.

Thus corrected cell type as `List<string>` added grid data to it, and then added cell to `List<InvoiceGrid>`.

```
        JQGridJSONReader input = new JQGridJSONReader();
        input.Page = 1;
        input.Total = 1;
        input.Records = 5;

        input.Rows = new List<InvoiceGrid>();


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            InvoiceGrid invGrid = new InvoiceGrid();
            invGrid.Cell = new List<string>();
            JqGridCell gridrows = new JqGridCell();
            gridrows.Invid = 1 + i;
            gridrows.Amount = 500.00 + (i * 10);
            gridrows.Tax = 65.00 + (i * 10);
            gridrows.Total = gridrows.Amount + gridrows.Tax;
            gridrows.Note = "myNote " + i.ToString();
            invGrid.Cell.Add(gridrows.Invid.ToString());
            invGrid.Cell.Add(gridrows.InvDate.ToString());
            invGrid.Cell.Add(gridrows.Amount.ToString());
            invGrid.Cell.Add(gridrows.Tax.ToString());
            invGrid.Cell.Add(gridrows.Total.ToString());
            invGrid.Cell.Add(gridrows.Note.ToString());
            input.Rows.Add(invGrid);
        }
```

I was thinking that error is because of `__type` as extra json data. But it seems jqGrid ignore this.

My json data now look like this.
Note:- I have ignored invid this time but can be included.

```
{"d":
{"__type":"JSONResponse:pe",
 "ActionType":"GRID_RESP",
 "JSONData":
            {"__type":"JQGridJSONReader:pe",
             "total":1,
             "page":1,
             "records":5,
             "rows":[
                    {"__type":"InvoiceGrid:pe",
                    "cell":["1","500","65","565","myNote 0"]},
                    {"__type":"InvoiceGrid:pe",
                    "cell":["2","510","75","585","myNote 1"]},
                    {"__type":"InvoiceGrid:pe",
                    "cell":["3","520","85","605","myNote 2"]},
                    {"__type":"InvoiceGrid:pe",
                    "cell":["4","530","95","625","myNote 3"]},
                    {"__type":"InvoiceGrid:pe",
                    "cell":["5","540","105","645","myNote 4"]}
                    ]
            },
 "Status":true
}}
```

Thanks a lot @Oleg.