# asp.net 2.0 asmx WebService Exclude __type in JSON Response

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to determine how to exclude `__type` in my JSON response from an asmx WebService.

The class that I am returning is constructed as follows.

```
public class MyClassName
{
    private string _item1 = string.Empty;
    private string _item2 = string.Empty;

    public string item1 = { get { return _item1; } set { _item1 = value; } }
    public string item2 = { get { return _item2; } set { _item2 = value; } }
}

public class MyClassName_List : List<MyClassName>
{
    public MyClassName_List() {}
}
```

I then have a Data Access Layer and Business Logic Layer that returns a populated instance of `MyClassName_List`. My WebMethod is setup as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyClassName_WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public MyClassName_List GetList()
    {
        return MyClassName_List_BusinessLogicLayer.GetList();
    }
}
```

The JSON object return is structured as follows.

```
[
    {
    item1: "item1-1 text",
    item2: "item1-2 text",
    __type: "NamespaceUsed.MyClassName"
    },
    {
    item1: "item2-1 text",
    item2: "item2-2 text",
    __type: "NamespaceUsed.MyClassName"
    },
]
```

I just want to return the JSON object as follows.

```
[
    {
    item1: "item1-1 text",
    item2: "item1-2 text"
    },
    {
    item1: "item2-1 text",
    item2: "item2-2 text"
    }
]
```

I have tried the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627356/how-to-not-serialize-the-type-property-on-json-objects), but I can not seem to implement it properly. Any help on this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to do this is follows.

```
public class MyClassName
{
    private string _item1 = string.Empty;
    private string _item2 = string.Empty;

    public string item1 = { get { return _item1; } set { _item1 = value; } }
    public string item2 = { get { return _item2; } set { _item2 = value; } }

    protected internal MyClassName() { } //add a protected internal constructor to remove the returned __type attribute in the JSON response
}

public class MyClassName_List : List<MyClassName>
{
    public MyClassName_List() {}
}
```

I hope this helps someone else too!

Comment: I've been searching for 2 hours, and this answer fixed it in a blip! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps! Let me know if you have any problems. I have been using this for quite some time now with no issues!

Comment: Great one thanks !
I had to tackle this problem in VB.net so, for those searching the VB equivalent : 

`Public Class MyClass
 Protected Friend Sub New()
        End Sub
End Class`