# How to remove prefix of underscore on "type" property in JSON result set

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, restful-url

Why is prefix of underscore on **Type** in my JSON Result Set?How to remove it? Thanks in advance

```
 {"SearchEncounterByIDResult":{"__type":"Encounter:#XYZServer.Data","Encounterlocation":[],"Hospitalization":{"AdmitSource":{"Coding":{}},"Destination":{"Address":{"Period":{}},"Identifier":{"Period":{}},"PartOf":{"Period":{}},"PhysicalType":{"Coding":{}},"Position":{},"Telecom":{"Period":{}},"Type":{"Coding":{}}},"Diet":{"Coding":{}},"DischargeDisposition":{"Coding":{}},"Origin":{"Address":{"Period":{}},"Identifier":{"Period":{}},"PartOf":{"Period":{}},"PhysicalType":{"Coding":{}},"Position":{},"Telecom":{"Period":{}},"Type":{"Coding":{}}},"Period":{},"PreAdmissionIdentifier":{"Period":{}},"SpecialArrangement":{"Coding":{}},"SpecialCourtesy":{"Coding":{}}},"Identifier":{"Period":{},"Value":"1"},"Lenght":{},"Participant":[],"Period":{"Start":"\/Date(1311102000000+0500)\/"},"Priority":{"Coding":{}},"Reason":{"Coding":{}},"ServiceProvider":{"Coding":{}},"Subject":{"Address":{"Country":"Punjab","Period":{}},"Animal":{"Breed":{"Coding":{}},"GenderStatus":{"Coding":{}},"Species":{"Coding":{}}},"BirthDate":"\/Date(-189406800000+0500)\/","Communication":{"Coding":{}},"Contact":[],"Gender":{"Coding":{},"Text":"Male"},"Identifier":{"Period":{},"Value":"89414"},"Link":[],"ManagingOrganization":{"Address":{"Period":{}},"Identifier":{"Period":{}},"Location":{"Address":{"Period":{}},"Identifier":{"Period":{}},"PartOf":{"Period":{}},"PhysicalType":{"Coding":{}},"Position":{},"Telecom":{"Period":{}},"Type":{"Coding":{}}},"OrganizationContact":[],"Telecom":{"Period":{}},"Type":{"Coding":{}}},"MaritalStatus":{"Coding":{}},"Name":{"Given":"Humma","Period":{}},"Photo":{},"Telecom":{"Period":{}}},"Type":{"Coding":{}}}}
```

Comment: We need more information than that. What are you using to hold the data until you serialize it? Classes? A dictionary? A JObject? If classes, do you control the source code, or are they third party? Also, how are you doing the serialization?

Comment: You might like to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/778016/665261

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm using WCF based Restful web services development using .NET C#. The _type is actually serialized automatically to the namespace of my resource object. What actually I want to remove it and customized it to serialized as "resourceType":"Encounter" ...