# How to show JSON data in C#

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I am new to WCF. I created one WCF service and returned the data as JSON data. I assigned the return data to GridView, it shows the data perfectly.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate="employee/{search}")] 
List<Employee> Listing(string search);
```

Now, I want to display the JSON string in <div> element (to verify the data). I tried to show the return data,

```
dvJson.InnerHtml = esc.Listing("s");
```

it shows like this

```
Employee[]
```

How to display JSON string in div element using C#?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution...

```
  JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  serializer.Serialize(esc.Listing("s"), sb);
  dvJson.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

**Output:**

```
  [{"ID":1,"Name":"Raja"},{"ID":2,"Name":"Manisha"},{"ID":4,"Name":"Sam"},{"ID":7,"Name":"Suresh"}]
```

**Using DataContractJsonSerializer**
(Pranav Singh code updated [2-4 lines])

**To avoid Type information**, set JSON Serializer setting **`EmitTypeInformation to "Never"`**, from JSON data.

```
  MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
  DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
  settings.EmitTypeInformation = System.Runtime.Serialization.EmitTypeInformation.Never;
  DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Employee>), settings);
  ser.WriteObject(stream1, esc.Listing("s"));
  stream1.Position = 0;
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
  dvJson.InnerHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class, refer [DataContractJsonSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

It's better than `JavaScriptSerializer` because it can **also** safely deserialize objects from a JSON string and it part of WCF.

Usage :

```
    MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer (typeof (List<Employee>));
    ser.WriteObject(stream1, esc.Listing("s"));
    stream1.Position = 0;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
    dvJson.InnerHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

**To avoid Type information** (replace the 2nd line with following code)

JSON Serializer setting: Set **`EmitTypeInformation to "Never"`** to avoid "__Type" information from the JSON data.

```
    DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.EmitTypeInformation = System.Runtime.Serialization.EmitTypeInformation.Never;
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Employee>), settings);
```

Comment: It shows output: [{"__type":"Employee:#Org","ID":1,"Name":"Raja"},{"__type":"Employee:#Org","ID":2,"Name":"Manisha"}]. Can we get the data without '__type":"Employee:#Org"' ?

Comment: n your web.config: instead of `<enableWebScript/>` element use `<webHttp/>` for your `endpointBehaviors`, e.g.:

`<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="MyServiceEndpoint">
    <webHttp/>
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627356/how-to-not-serialize-the-type-property-on-json-objects